# How to write XSLT test condition with two functions

Tags: xslt

I want to test the input with 2 conditions.
I tried with below statement,

```
<xsl:when test="(string-lenght(/ns0:PostalCode) &lt; 9) and (string-lenght(/ns0:InoutCode/ns0:PostalCode) &gt; 5)">
```

but when I am testing the service it's getting below error
**The XPath expression failed to execute; the reason was: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException.**
Please help me on this issue. How write exact condition?

Comment: Are the `string-lenght()` typos in the real code or just in your post?

Comment: It would be really helpful if post your source xml file

Comment: Hi Saurav, Real code is diffrent. The condition could be, if the input data satisfied with  <9 and >5 then only dispaly the output. so Number 6,7 and 8 comes then pnly its true.

Answer (score 0):

Do two things:

(a) check the spelling of your function names

(b) find out why you aren't getting any proper diagnostics. You're either using an XPath engine with particularly bad diagnostics, or you aren't running it properly.

Comment: Hi MIchael, function names everything correct. still iam getting error like The XPath expression failed to execute; the reason was: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: XML-22900: (Fatal Error) An internal error condition occurred..

Comment: Issue resolved. Just rewrite the syntax and its working